# Preventing evaluation of Mathematica expressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In a recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4851948/421225) three different answers were supplied each using a different method of preventing the evaluation of the `Equal[]` expression.  They were

1. `Defer[]`
2. `Unevaluated[]`
3. `HoldForm[]`

Sometimes I still have trouble choosing between these options (and judging by answers to the [before mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4851948/421225), the choice isn't always clear for other people either).  Can someone write a clear exposition on the use of these three methods?

---

There are three other wrappers
 `Hold[]`,
 `HoldPattern[]`,
 `HoldComplete[]`,
and the various `Attributes` for functions 
 `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, `HoldRest` and the numeric versions `NHold*` that can also be discussed if you wish!

### Edit

I just noticed that this is basically a repeat of the old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1616592/421225) (which I had already upvoted, just forgotten...). The accepted answer linked to [this talk](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/) at the 1999 Mathematica Developer Conference, which doesn't discuss `Defer` since it is "New in 6". `Defer` is more closely linked to the frontend than the other evaluation control mechanisms.  It is used to create an unevaluated output that will be evaluated if supplied in and `Input` expression. To quote the [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html):

> Defer[expr] returns an object which
>   remains unchanged until it is
>   explicitly supplied as Mathematica
>   input, and evaluated using
>   Shift+Enter, Evaluate in Place, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that source. Have known about it for a long time, but never actually found time to have a closer look at it. I learned this from a different source, so this ref did not come to my mind, while it is probably more relevant than those I gave.

Comment: @Simon - This was in my pile somewhere too. And magically happens to be what I'm working on (err, should be working on).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not touching `Defer`, since I did not work much with it and feel that in any given case its behavior can be reproduced by other mentioned wrappers, and discussing `Hold` instead on `HoldForm` (the difference is really in the way they are printed), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bfd67e9122b1fdec) is the link to a mathgroup post where I gave a rather extensive explanation of differences between `Hold` and `Unevaluated`, including differences in usage and in the evaluation process (my second and third posts in particular).

To put the long story short, `Hold` is used to preserve an expression unevaluated in between several evaluations (for indefinite time, until we need it), is a visible wrapper in the sense that say `Depth[Hold[{1,2,3}]]` is not the same as `Depth[{1,2,3}]` (this is of course a consequence of evaluation), and is generally nothing special - just a wrapper with `HoldAll` attribute like any other, except being an "official" holding wrapper and being integrated much better with the rest of the system, since many system functions use or expect it.

OTOH, `Unevaluated[expr]` is used to temporarily, just once, make up for a missing Hold* attribute for a function enclosing expression `expr`. While resulting in behavior which would require this enclosing function to hold `expr` as if it had `Hold*` - attribute, `Unevaluated` belongs to the argument, and works only once, for a single evaluation, since it gets stripped in the process. Also, because it gets stripped, it often is invisible for the surrounding wrappers, unlike `Hold`. Finally, it is one of a very few "magic symbols", along with `Sequence` and `Evaluate` - these are deeply wired into the system and can not be easily replicated or blocked, unlike `Hold` - in that sense, `Unevaluated` is more fundamental.

`HoldComplete` is used when one wants to prevent certain stages of evaluation process, which `Hold` does not prevent. This includes splicing sequences, for example:

```
In[25]:= {Hold[Sequence[1, 2]], HoldComplete[Sequence[1, 2]]}

Out[25]= {Hold[1, 2], HoldComplete[Sequence[1, 2]]},
```

search for `UpValues`, for example

```
In[26]:= 
ClearAll[f];
f /: Hold[f[x_]] := f[x];
f[x_] := x^2;

In[29]:= {Hold[f[5]], HoldComplete[f[5]]},

Out[29]= {25, HoldComplete[f[5]]}
```

and immunity to `Evaluate`:

```
In[33]:= 
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := x^2;

In[35]:= {Hold[Evaluate[f[5]]], HoldComplete[Evaluate[f[5]]]}

Out[35]= {Hold[25], HoldComplete[Evaluate[f[5]]]}
```

In other words, it is used when you want to prevent any evaluation of the expression inside, whatsoever. Like `Hold`, `HoldComplete` is nothing special in the sense that it is just an "official" wrapper with `HoldAllComplete` attribute, and you can make your own which would behave similarly.

Finally, `HoldPattern` is a normal (usual) head with `HoldAll` attribute for the purposes of evaluation, but its magic shows in the pattern-matching: it is invisible to the pattern-matcher, and is very important ingredient of the language since it allows pattern-matcher to be consistent with the evaluation process. Whenever there is a danger that the pattern in some rule may evaluate, `HoldPattern` can be used to ensure that this won't happen, while the pattern remains the same for the pattern-matcher. One thing I'd stress here that this is the only purpose for it. Often people use it also as an escape mechanism for the pattern-matcher, where `Verbatim` must be used instead. This works, but is conceptually wrong.

One very good account on evaluation process and all these things is a book of David Wagner, *Power programming with Mathematica - the kernel*, which was written in 1996 for version 3, but most if not all of the discussion there remains valid today. It is out of print alas, but you might have some luck on Amazon (as I had a few years ago).

Comment: I love the phrases/ideas *"official" holding wrapper* and the *few "magic symbols"*. And these phrases actually do bring back memories of your mathgroup post.

Comment: @Simon: *"magic symbols"* I stole from Wagner (he calls them *"magic cookies"*), *"official"* is mine :). Actually, his exposition is by far the best I've seen (not having read the one by Villegas), though even it could benefit from having a few more illustrations of the subtleties involved, like examples I gave in that post.

Comment: Can anyone give me an example where it is advantageous to use Defer instead of HoldForm?

Answer (score 6):

[Leonid Shifrin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions/4856721#4856721) answer is quite nice, but I wanted to touch on `Defer`, which is really useful for only one thing. In some instances, it's nice to be able to directly construct expressions that won't be evaluated, but that a user will be able to easily edit; the basic example for this kind of behavior is button palettes that you can use to insert expressions or expression templates into input cells which the user can then edit as needed. This isn't the only way to do this, and for some more sophisticated applications you'll need to get into the hairy world `MakeBoxes`, but for the basics `Defer` will serve nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I usually work with boxes when I need this kind of functionality, but it's nice to know anyway - could indeed be simpler to use `Defer` in some cases.