# What does "upvalue" mean in Mathematica and when to use them?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

To me, `g /: f[g[x_]] := h[x]` is just verbose equivalent of `f[g[x_]] := h[x]`. Can you raise an example that you have to use `/:`?

Comment: It's got to do with where the definition is stored. Maybe you should read [Associating Definitions with Different Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html)

Comment: Consider the help example `g /: g[x_] + g[y_] := gplus[x, y]` vs trying a transformation rule for every expression just to check if two `g[ ]` are added up

Comment: Related MathGroups post: ["Tags, Upset, UpValues ..."](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/8bd4917ffa062f3e).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, `g /: f[g[x_]] := h[x]` is not equivalent to `f[g[x_]] := h[x]`.  The latter associates the definition with `f`, while [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSet.html?q=TagSet&lang=en) (`/:`) and [`UpSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSet.html?q=UpSet&lang=en) (`^=` and its [delayed version](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html?q=UpSetDelayed&lang=en), `^:=`) associate the definition with `g`. This is a crucial difference and can be illustrated by a simple example.  Let's say you want to have a set of variables that obey modulo 5 addition, i.e. 6 + 7 mod 5 = 3. So, we want anything with `Head` `mod` to behave correctly. Initially, we'd think that

```
a_mod + b_mod := mod@Mod[a + b, 5]
```

would work. But, it generates the error

```
SetDelayed::write : Tag Plus in a_mod + b_mod is Protected.
```

We could remove `Unprotect` `Plus` and our definition would then work, but this may cause problems with other definitions and as `Plus` accumulates more definitions, it would slow down.  Alternatively, we can associate the addition property with the `mod` object itself via `TagSet`

```
mod /: mod[a_] + mod[b_] := mod @ Mod[a + b, 5]
```

or `UpSetDelayed`

```
mod[a_] + mod[b_] ^:= mod @ Mod[a + b, 5]
```

Setting an [upvalue](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpValues.html?q=UpValues&lang=en) is somewhat more correct from a conceptual point of view since `mod` is the one with the different property.

There are a couple of issues to be aware of.  First, the upvalue mechanism can only scan one level deep, i.e. `Plus[a_mod, b_mod]` is fine, but `Exp[Plus[a_mod, b_mod]]` will throw an error.  This may require you to get creative with an intermediate type. Secondly, from a coding perspective `UpSetDelayed` is easier to write, but occasionally there is some ambiguity as to which `Head` is the upvalue associated with.  `TagSet` handles that by explicitly naming the appropriate `Head`, and in general, it is what I tend to prefer over `UpSet`.

Some of Mathematica's operators do not have any behavior associated with them, so they're not protected.  For these operators, you can define functions as you wish. For instance, I've defined

```
a_ \[CircleTimes] b_ := KroneckerProduct[a,b]
a_ \[CircleTimes] b_ \[CircleTimes] c__ := a \[CircleTimes] ( b \[CircleTimes] c )
```

and

```
a_ \[CirclePlus] b__ := BlockDiagonal[{a,b}]
```

to provide convenient shorthand notations for matrix operations that I use a lot.

My example above was a little contrived, but there are a number of times `UpValues` have come in handy. For example, I found that I needed a symbolic form for the complex roots of unity that behaved appropriately under multiplication and exponentiation.

**Example**: A straightforward and useful example is marking a `Symbol` as Real:

```
makeReal[a__Symbol] := (
     # /: Element[#, Reals] := True; 
     # /: Im[#] := 0; 
     # /: Re[#] := #;
     # /: Abs[#] := Sign[#] #;
     # /: Arg[#] := Piecewise[{{0, Sign[#] >= 0}, {Pi, Sign[#] < 0}}]
   ) & /@ List[a]
```

Note the use of `TagSet` as `Element[ a, Reals ] ^:= True` would be ambiguous. What would the rule be attached to `a` or `Reals`? Also, if we wanted a positive real number, we could set `Arg[#]:=0` which allows `Simplify` to behave as expected, e.g. `Simplify[Sqrt[a^2]] == a`.

Comment: Shouldn't the example be something like `mod /: a_mod + b_mod := mod@Mod[Delete[a, 0] + Delete[b, 0], 5]`? I'm getting recursion errors otherwise. Maybe I'm missing something, trying to wrap my head around upserts.

Comment: Or better `mod /: a_mod + b_mod := mod@Mod[Identity@@a + Identity@@b, 5]`

Comment: @gleno good catch. I think the better alternative is to use `mod[a_] + mod[b_]`, much simpler. At the time, I think I was enamored with using the `Head` in the pattern (which is till neat), but it is less useful if you need to use the internals.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the excellent answer by @rcollyer, I'd like to emphasize a few other important things about `UpValues`.

#### Soft/local redefinition of system and other functions

One very important aspect is that they allow you to "softly" overload some system functions only on certain symbols. The importance of this was pointed out by @rcollyer, but can not be emphasized enough - this makes the effect of your code local, and drastically reduces the chances that your code can globally interact and affect some other part of the system or other piece of user-defined code, unlike when you `Unprotect` system symbols and add some `DownValues` to them.

In addition to being safe and local, such redefinitions may also be quite general, if one uses constructs like `yourSymbol/:f_[_yourSymbol,rest___]:=...`. These should be used with care, but can sometimes give very concise and simple solutions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451802/pattern-to-match-only-children-of-certain-elements/6453673#6453673) is one example where one code can be used to "overload" several system functions at once, giving them additional non-trivial functionality.

#### Order of evaluation

The next point is evaluation. The common statement you can encounter is that "`UpValues` are applied before `DownValues`". This must be clarified: for `f[g[args]]` it means that `UpValues` for `g` are applied before `DownValues` for `f`, provided that the evaluation process already went all they way "down" to innermost parts, and then went back "up". In particular, it does not mean that `UpValues` for `g` will be applied before `DownValues` for `g` - if `g[args]` can evaluate inside `f` because `g` has appropriate `DownValues`, it will (unless f has one of the `Hold`-attributes), and the presence of `UpValues` won't prevent that, because (for standard evaluation), evaluation of `g[args]` happens before the evaluation of `f[result-of-evaluation-of g[args]]`. For example, here:

```
In[58]:= 
ClearAll[f, g];
f[x_] := x^2;
g /: f[g[x_]] := Sin[g[x]];
g[x_] := Cos[x];

In[62]:= f[g[y]]
Out[62]= Cos[y]^2
```

The `UpValues` for `g` had no chance to apply, since `g[y]` is transformed into `Cos[y]` at the previous evaluation step. The situation would be different for non-standard evaluation - either if we give `f` attributes `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`, or if we wrap `g[y]` in `Unevaluated` - in both cases we give the evaluator the instruction to skip the evaluation of `g[y]`:

```
In[63]:= f[Unevaluated[g[y]]]

Out[63]= Sin[Cos[y]]
```

#### Escaping Hold-attributes

This one is related to the previous point: one should be aware that search for `UpValues` is performed even inside heads with `Hold`- attributes, and therefore, `UpValue`-based definitions may evaluate even when similarly-looking `DownValue` - based ones won't. Example:

```
In[64]:= ClearAll[f,ff];
f[x_]:=Print["Evaluated"];
ff/:h_[ff[x_]]:=Print["Evaluated"];

In[67]:= Hold[f[1]]
Out[67]= Hold[f[1]]

In[68]:= Hold[ff[1]]
During evaluation of In[68]:= Evaluated
```

If one wants to absolutely prevent the search for `UpValues`, one should give a function the `HoldAllComplete` attribute. For example:

```
In[69]:= {HoldComplete[f[1]],HoldComplete[ff[1]]}
Out[69]= {HoldComplete[f[1]],HoldComplete[ff[1]]}
```

#### Level-1 tag depth restriction

This was already mentioned by @rcollyer. This limitation was introduced for efficiency of the pattern-matcher/evaluator. I just want to stress one important and rather non-obvious consequence of it: it looks like you can not use `UpValues` to overload assignment (`Set` operator) so that it would work on variables assigned to objects of some specific type you introduce. Here is an attempt:

```
In[74]:= 
ClearAll[a,myType,myCustomCode,newValue];
myType/:Set[var_myType,rhs_]:=myCustomCode;
```

This seems to work. But let us try:

```
In[79]:= a = myType[1, 2, 3];
a = newValue;
a

Out[81]= newValue
```

It does not do what we want, obviously. The problem is that `Set` holds its l.h.s., so by the time the pattern-matching happens, it only has the symbol `a`, not its value. And because we can not associate the definition with tags deeper than on the first level of the expression, the following won't work either:

```
ClearAll[a,myType,myCustomCode,newValue];
myType/:Set[var_,rhs_]/;MatchQ[var,_myType]:=myCustomCode;
TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag myType in (var_=rhs_)/;MatchQ[var,_myType]
  is too deep for an assigned rule to be found. >>
```

To my knowledge, `UpValues` can not be used to solve this problem, which is a pity, since having a usual `=` syntax with custom assignment code for various data types would be convenient. For a similar discussion, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886066/overloading-seta-b-a-b/5886322#5886322) post. This situation is not unique for `Set` - the same would hold for any function that holds the argument that you want to use for your `UpValue`-based definition.

#### Some differences between `UpSet` and `TagSet`, `UpSetDelayed` and `TagSetDelayed`

It is worth knowing that when you use `UpSet` or `UpSetDelayed`, then *all*  tags at level 1 acquire additional definitions (rules). For example:

```
Clear[a,b];
Plus[a,b]^:=1;

?a
Global`a
a/:a+b:=1

?b
Global`b
b/:a+b:=1
```

In contrast with this, `TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed` are more precise:

```
ClearAll[a,b];
a/:Plus[a,b]:=1;

?a
Global`a
a/:a+b:=1

?b
Global`b
```

In my experience, the latter behavior is usually more desirable, so in most cases I prefer `TagSet` or `TagSetDelayed` over `UpSet` or `UpSetDelayed`.

Comment: +1, like always and for reminding me that `TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed` are ternary operators.

Comment: while it doesn't work quite as expected, I have been able to overload `SetDelayed` [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174791/preventing-avalanche-of-runtime-errors-in-mathematica/4176381#4176381). Ah, I see why, my specifically uses symbols, not their values, so the restriction does not hold.

Comment: @rcollyer You can overload `SetDelyaed` on explicit symbols with `UpValues`, that's true. I did not fully explore this possibility myself, but it may well be that this can be used constructively and in interesting ways. This recent answer by @WReach comes to mind as one such example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917656/possible-to-block-ownvalues-when-downvalues-already-exist/6919530#6919530

Comment: I had not looked at that question. Interesting method.

Comment: @Leonid Re: order of evaluation

when evaluating f[g[arg]] the order is: downvalues of g, upvalues of g, downvalues of f .
Downvalues of g are evaluated BEFORE upvalues of g.
However if you look at ?g you will see that upvalues are listed before downvalues. So the presentation order is somewhat misleading.
Do you agree?

Comment: @Leonid by the way: where is it written in the documentation that downvalues[g] are evaluates before upvalues[g]? I know it is correct, but I cannot find it written anywhere explicitly. At least not in the obvious places.

Comment: @magma The thing is that `DownValues` for `g` apply on the "previous evaluation cycle", w.r.t. `UpValues` for `g`. When we read about standard  evaluation sequence, we see that first the heads are evaluated, then parts (recursively, evaluation "goes down" the expression tree), then evaluation goes "up", so that attributes are used, and finally rules are applied. For `f[g[x]]`, at this step first `UpValues` for `g` apply, then `DownValues` for `f`. But, `g[x]` was evaluated (and `DownValues[g]` applied) during the previous  recursive step of (sub) part evalution - I call it "previous cycle".

Answer (score 9):

Rcollyer has already given an excellent answer but here is an *example* of when you might use `UpValues`: when you are defining a particular data structure, with its own `Head`, and you want to defining how built in operations like arithmetic work with that structure. I once did this for a `timeSeries` data structure where, for example, addition would match up the dates in the first columns and add the corresponding pairs of values in the second columns. Adding T * 2 vectors with dates in the first column would give nonsense dates if you hadn't defined such an operation using an `UpValue`.

Comment: I've used `makeReal` often enough. I normally have to rewrite it every time, though, since it is trivial. But, more usefully, I've done the same thing you have as a program I work with produces spin densities and I wanted total density (spin-up + spin-dn) and magnetization (spin-up - spin-dn), and the object representation wasn't simple.