# Addition of Functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So generally, if you have two functions f,g: X -->Y, and if there is some binary operation + defined on Y, then f + g has a canonical definition as the function x --> f(x) + g(x).

What's the best way to implement this in Mathematica?

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := 2*x
h = f + g;
h[1]
```

yields

```
(f + g)[1]
```

as an output

of course,

```
H = Function[z, f[z] + g[z]];
H[1]
```

Yields '3'.

Comment: Thank you, and +1  (By the way, it is better not to sign your messages, as this is redundant, being that your identity block it below every question or answer.)

Answer (score 13):

Consider:

```
In[1]:= Through[(f + g)[1]]

Out[1]= f[1] + g[1]
```

To elaborate, you can define `h` like this:

```
h = Through[ (f + g)[#] ] &;
```

If you have a limited number of functions and operands, then `UpSet` as recommended by yoda is surely syntactically cleaner.  However, `Through` is more general.  Without any new definitions involving `Times` or `h`, one can easily do:

```
i = Through[ (h * f * g)[#] ] &
i[7]
```

```
43218
```

Comment: Thanks for the `Through` function; I did not know about that!

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I'm writing a gram-schmidt function; it would be nice if it worked for generic objects posing as vectors, such as functions, lists, etc. I think probably the best thing to do is have as optional arguments, 'add' and 'scale', so that you can define what vector addition and scaling is, so the gramm-schmidt function would work on general objects.

Comment: @ yoda, see previous comment: I'll have long lists of functions, which will be the projections of the next vector on to the spans of the previous, orthonormalized vectors.

Comment: @nmaxwell, depending on your familiarity with *Mathematica*, you may find this informative:  `combine[{__funcs}, _operator] := Through[operator[funcs][#]] &` -- you can use it like `h = combine[{f,g}, Plus]`.

Comment: The package PushThrough of David Park uses Through to answer similar questions: http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/Mathematica.html

Comment: @Faysal, I must have seen that before, but I cannot recall it.  It appears useful and appropriate.

Comment: @nmaxwell Might want to have a look at Orthogonalize and  Projection.

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing what you're trying to do is using `UpSetDelayed`.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := 2*x;

f + g ^:= f[#] + g[#] &; (*define upvalues for the operation f+g*)

h[x_] = f + g;

h[z]

Out[1]= 2 z + z^2
```

Also see [this very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them/6650884#6650884) by rcollyer (and also the ones by Leonid & Verbeia) for more on `UpValues` and when to use them

Comment: +1 -- I didn't suggest UpSet because I took the question to be generic for a variety of functions rather than specifically `f` and `g`.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right... It was his last statement that suggested he was thinking of overloading operators made me post an answer that would point towards it. Besides, I couldn't think of any other and actually waited for about 5-10 mins after you answered just to see if you'll do a quick ninja edit to include `UpSet` :D

Answer (score 3):

I will throw in a complete code for Gram - Schmidt and an example for function addition etc, since I happened to have that code written about 4 years ago. Did not test extensively though. I did not change a single line of it now, so a disclaimer (I was a lot worse at mma at the time). That said, here is a Gram - Schmidt procedure implementation, which is a slightly generalized version of the code I discussed [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node237.html):

```
oneStepOrtogonalizeGen[vec_, {}, _, _, _] := vec;

oneStepOrtogonalizeGen[vec_, vecmat_List, dotF_, plusF_, timesF_] := 
    Fold[plusF[#1, timesF[-dotF[vec, #2]/dotF[#2, #2], #2]] &, vec,  vecmat];

GSOrthogonalizeGen[startvecs_List, dotF_, plusF_, timesF_] := 
    Fold[Append[#1,oneStepOrtogonalizeGen[#2, #1, dotF, plusF, timesF]] &, {},  startvecs];

normalizeGen[vec_, dotF_, timesF_] := timesF[1/Sqrt[dotF[vec, vec]], vec];

GSOrthoNormalizeGen[startvecs_List, dotF_, plusF_, timesF_] := 
  Map[normalizeGen[#, dotF, timesF] &, GSOrthogonalizeGen[startvecs, dotF, plusF, timesF]];
```

The functions above are parametrized by 3 functions, realizing addition, multiplication by a number, and the dot product in a given vector space. The example to illustrate will be to find `Hermite` polynomials by orthonormalizing monomials. These are possible implementations for the 3 functions we need:

```
hermiteDot[f_Function, g_Function] := 
   Module[{x}, Integrate[f[x]*g[x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]];

SetAttributes[functionPlus, {Flat, Orderless, OneIdentity}];
functionPlus[f__Function] :=   With[{expr = Plus @@ Through[{f}[#]]}, expr &];

SetAttributes[functionTimes, {Flat, Orderless, OneIdentity}];
functionTimes[a___, f_Function] /; FreeQ[{a}, # | Function] := 
      With[{expr = Times[a, f[#]]}, expr &];
```

These functions may be a bit naive, but they will illustrate the idea (and yes, I also used `Through`). Here are some examples to illustrate their use:

```
In[114]:= hermiteDot[#^2 &, #^4 &]
Out[114]= (15 Sqrt[\[Pi]])/8

In[107]:= functionPlus[# &, #^2 &, Sin[#] &]
Out[107]= Sin[#1] + #1 + #1^2 &

In[111]:= functionTimes[z, #^2 &, x, 5]
Out[111]= 5 x z #1^2 &
```

Now, the main test:

```
In[115]:= 
results = 
  GSOrthoNormalizeGen[{1 &, # &, #^2 &, #^3 &, #^4 &}, hermiteDot, 
      functionPlus, functionTimes]

Out[115]= {1/\[Pi]^(1/4) &, (Sqrt[2] #1)/\[Pi]^(1/4) &, (
  Sqrt[2] (-(1/2) + #1^2))/\[Pi]^(1/4) &, (2 (-((3 #1)/2) + #1^3))/(
  Sqrt[3] \[Pi]^(1/4)) &, (Sqrt[2/3] (-(3/4) + #1^4 - 
  3 (-(1/2) + #1^2)))/\[Pi]^(1/4) &}
```

These are indeed the properly normalized Hermite polynomials, as is easy to verify. The normalization of built-in `HermiteH` is different. Our results are normalized as one would normalize the wave functions of a harmonic oscillator, say. It is trivial to obtain a list of polynomials as expressions depending on a variable, say x:

```
In[116]:= Through[results[x]]
Out[116]= {1/\[Pi]^(1/4),(Sqrt[2] x)/\[Pi]^(1/4),(Sqrt[2] (-(1/2)+x^2))/\[Pi]^(1/4),
(2 (-((3 x)/2)+x^3))/(Sqrt[3] \[Pi]^(1/4)),(Sqrt[2/3] (-(3/4)+x^4-3 (-(1/2)+x^2)))/\[Pi]^(1/4)}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest defining an operator other than the built-in `Plus` for this purpose.  There are a number of operators provided by Mathematica that are reserved for user definitions in cases such as this.  One such operator is `CirclePlus` which has no pre-defined meaning but which has a nice compact representation (at least, it is compact in a notebook -- not so compact on a StackOverflow web page).  You could define `CirclePlus` to perform function addition thus:

```
(x_ \[CirclePlus] y_)[args___] := x[args] + y[args]
```

With this definition in place, you can now perform function addition:

```
h = f \[CirclePlus] g;
h[x]
(* Out[3]= f[x]+g[x] *)
```

If one likes to live on the edge, the same technique can be used with the built-in `Plus` operator provided it is unprotected first:

```
Unprotect[Plus];
(x_ + y_)[args___] := x[args] + y[args]
Protect[Plus];

h = f + g;
h[x]
(* Out[7]= f[x]+g[x] *)
```

I would generally advise against altering the behaviour of built-in functions -- especially one as fundamental as `Plus`.  The reason is that there is no guarantee that user-added definitions to `Plus` will be respected by other built-in or kernel functions.  In some circumstances calls to `Plus` are optimized, and those optimizations might be not take the user definitions into account.  However, this consideration may not affect any particular application so the option is still a valid, if risky, design choice.

Comment: Like the OP says, function addition is canonically defined and so any other definition is a *deviation* of what all mathematicians expect.